# Misplaced Rows In An Asterisk-Built, ASCII-Art Pyramid Made Using Multiple For Loops In PHP

Tags: php, ascii-art

here is my code i need to fix this pyramid  here you can see the display and the code
the problem is that

```
         *        * *//these i want to fix
       *   *
      *     *
     *       *
    *         *
   *           *
  *             *
 *               *
*                 *
```

```
$n = 10;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < ($n - $i); $j++)
        echo " ";
    echo "*";
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $i-1; $j++)
        echo " ";
    for ($k = 1; $k < $i-1; $k++)
        echo " ";
    if($i!=1)
        echo "*</br>";
}
```

**[Demo of Broken Code](https://ideone.com/uZz0Qu)**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include any debugging steps you have already taken yourself to try to determine the issue. There's another link on that page that explains how/why to debug in more detail: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: This is likely due to how web-browsers collapse whitespace. Render it inside a `<pre></pre>` element to preserve whitespace.

Comment: Also, I'd like to say, welcome to SO!  Let me know if my answer is of any help, and if it's not, what's not right.  I also updated your question with a demo -- so others can see clearly what the problem is.  Hope this, helps!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have `if($i!=1)` as a condition within the end of the first `$i` for loop.  This actually needs to be moved to the first, sub-for loop.

*Why is this?*  Well, your `$i` for loop is printing two `*`'s.  At the top of the pyramid, though, you only have *one `*` symbol*.  In this case, we need to exclude displaying in that case, but only in that case.

[**Full Working Demo.**](https://ideone.com/tKZnLX)

```
$n = 10;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
        {
            for ($j = 0; $j < ($n - $i); $j++)
                echo " ";
                if($i!=1) {
                    echo "*";
                }
            for ($j = 1; $j <= $i-1; $j++)
                echo " ";
            for ($k = 1; $k < $i-1; $k++)
                echo " ";
                echo "*\n";
        }
```

Full output:

```
         *
        * *
       *   *
      *     *
     *       *
    *         *
   *           *
  *             *
 *               *
*                 *
```

You had two stray `*` displaying.  The second was caused by cases after `$i == 1` being displayed in the first for loop on `$i`, and the first was caused by not ignoring the `*` symbol on the first case of `$i` in the `$j` for loop.

Answer (score 0):

[play for example](https://www.tehplayground.com/SL4bQqOjIpLPf5va)

```php
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {

    echo str_repeat(' ',15-$i). "*" . str_repeat(' ', 2*$i) . "*\n";
}

echo ' '.str_repeat('*', 31)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ($i != 1)` is skipping over the new line output when `$i` is 1, which is why your second "line" is being output on the first line still. If you change the logic around outputting `<br>` it will work.

```
$n = 10;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < ($n - $i); $j++) {
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "*";
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $i-1; $j++) {
        echo " ";
    }
    for ($k = 1; $k < $i-1; $k++) {
        echo " ";
    }
    
    if ($i != 1) {
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

```
         *
        * *
       *   *
      *     *
     *       *
    *         *
   *           *
  *             *
 *               *
*                 *
```